# Fragments contents overlap each other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have used the documentation provided by google. All is well but the contents of fragments overlap each other when switched by tabs.

Here is the code.

Main Activity

```
public class login_register extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_register);
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#009688")));
            ActionBar.Tab  loginTab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            ActionBar.Tab   RegisterTab = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            RegisterTab.setText("Register");
            loginTab.setText("Login");
            RegisterTab.setTabListener(new TabListener<register>(this, "register", register.class));
            loginTab.setTabListener(new TabListener<login>(this, "login", login.class));
            actionBar.addTab(loginTab);
            actionBar.addTab(RegisterTab);
    }

    public  class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;
        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
        }

        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
           mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

            if (mFragment == null ) {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the one of the fragments.

```
public class login extends Fragment {
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any help please.

Edit
Here is the picture

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "overlap ". Please explain further and perhaps provide a screenshot.

Comment: I have added the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
}
```

`fragmentTransaction.add(...)` will add the supplied fragment to the view on top of anything that's already there. You want to replace the existing one instead:

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
```

Comment: It better use `attach` and `detach`! Because `Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fragmentTransaction.add(...)` also, set `android:background` property to both fragments layout to solve this issue.

Comment: have you set android:background to mainlayout of both fragments ?

Comment: I have added android:background="@android:color/transparent" can u please post the example code of mainlayout and fragments?

Comment: With transparent color obviously you will see behind fragment, :(  try with some other color like white to solve this overlapping issue.

Comment: if there is any edittext in layout then this trick hide that edittext.

Comment: No, your top fragment will look as you designed just background fragment will get hide and I think you want that only.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onTabSelected` use:

```
ft.attach(mFragment).commit(); replace ft.attach(mFragment);
```

In your `onUnTabSelected`, `detach` should be when `if (mFragment != null )`, 
so it should be:

```
     if (mFragment != null ) {
            ft.detach(mFragment).commit();
        }
```